# Notify java app when something has happened by another java app

Tags: java, ipc

I want to notify my java app when a DML has occur on my DB. I can call java.jar in the MySQL trigger with `sys_exec('/path/to/javabin -jar my.jar');`

What I'm missing is how to do it JAVA-wise.

1. I need that `my.jar` will send to my general app a message(or something).
2. I need that my general app listen to incoming messages(but not wait for them), open new thread and execute code.

I have no idea how to do this 2 parts.

Some people suggested semaphores, signals, messaging system. I did some internet search with not helpful direction. I can't use 3rd party software due.

Comment: Comment on the question problem so I can rewrite my question accordingly.

Comment: Messaging seems to be a good option here. ( you can try ActiveMQ in point-to-point mode. - Ex Ref -http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will have to use Networkcommunication between the two applications.

For example, great Librarys are KryoNet (https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) and Netty (http://netty.io/)

Comment: With those things you can even communicate between the apps if they arent located on the same pc.

Comment: Thanks, Netty was a problem but with Kryo I manage to set it up in one minute.